# 'serenity-bdd run' gives 'The "path" argument must be of type string' error in Docker

Tags: docker, serenity-js

I have a Serenity-JS project that runs normally on the command line. I am trying to package it into a Docker container for use in an Azure pipeline, which is a model we've used with other projects.

However, when I run the project via Docker, the tests execute correctly but the step to generate report documentation fails with a rather terse error:

```
[test:report] > serenity-bdd run
[test:report] 
[test:report] I'm terribly sorry, but something didn't go according to plan:
[test:report] The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null
```

Nothing else shows up in the output, so the source of the issue isn't clear. I'm not even sure which `path` argument this is referring to. I've dug into the Serenity-JS Node module but I don't see a clear culprit here, nor do I understand why it would work via command line but not in Docker. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The short fix

**Install Java Development Kit - JDK**

The Fast Way:

On Windows with Chocolatey

> choco install jdk8

On Unix or Max

> apt install jdk8

The Easy Way:

Read and follow the Serenity BDD Install Guide.
https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/first-steps.html

I tried to install a newer `openjdk` e.g. 11 or 16 but that gave me issues on Windows.

The reason:

serenity-js cannot start the serenity-bdd java module, since it can't find Java.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this later, I found the solution: the base image I was using didn't have a Java runtime, which `serenity-bdd` uses under the hood. Switching to an `openjdk` base image and manually installing my Node dependencies got around this issue.